# How to work with audio autoplay

Tags: html, audio, autoplay

My code:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="music/music1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="music/music2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

But this code will play booth music together..
I need play it gradually. (Play first, wait while first will end, then play second.).

How to do this guys? Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can directly create a continuous playlist using just the HTMl5 audio tag. Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282461/3102766) for a way to do this with Javascript.