# How to play many audio files in sequence

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have several long stories which for which the source audio is sentence-by-sentence audio files.  I would like to create a web page where one could listen to individual sentences of a particular story many times, or listen to the whole story from start to finish.

To start, my web page has many `<audio>` elements, each of which is in a `<p>` with the corresponding text.  Each of these `<audio>` elements corresponds to a single sentence of the story.

I was about to start coding up a javascript object which was going to allow some sort of "play all" functionality, you'd click the button and it would play audio[0], when that finished, audio[1], etc.  It would also have a 'pause' button and keep track of where you were, etc.  This way the individual sentences could still be played or enjoyed because they each have an `audio` element.  Or, one could use my "play all" buttons at the top to treat the sequence of `audio` elements as if they were one big element.

Then I started asking myself if there's some better/easier/more canonical solution here.  One thing I thought of doing would be to cat all of these individual audio files together into a big audio file and perhaps create 'chapter' `<track>` elements.  Is this preferable?

What are the pros and cons to each approach?  Is there some out-of-the-box solution already made for me which I simply haven't turned up?

Comment: Your question is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274061/html-5-audio-tag-multiple-files

Comment: Similar, but not the same.  That question asks whether it's possible to control more than one audio element with javascript.  I think it's clearly possible and I see how to do it (more or less).  My question is whether this is a good idea.  Or, perhaps more to the point, whether it's a better idea than catting my audio files together and creating some sort of chaptering system.  Or, whether there's some third solution I'm missing here.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the ended event to play the next sound when the previous sound completes ([Playing HTML 5 Audio sequentially via Javascript](https://pro9ram.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/playing-html-5-audio-sequentially-via-javascript/)):

```
var sounds = new Array(new Audio("1.mp3"), new Audio("2.mp3"));
var i = -1;
playSnd();

function playSnd() {
    i++;
    if (i == sounds.length) return;
    sounds[i].addEventListener('ended', playSnd);
    sounds[i].play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function playAudio(src) {
  var audioElement = new Audio(src);
  audioElement.play();
  return audioElement
}

const sequences = ['./audio/person.m4a', './audio/4.m4a', './audio/5.m4a', './audio/6.m4a', './audio/6.m4a', './audio/6.m4a', './audio/room.m4a', './audio/3.m4a']

// play audio
let index = 0
const audioElement = playAudio(sequences[index])
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', (e) => {
  index++
  if (index < sequences.length) {
    audioElement.src = sequences[index]
    audioElement.play();
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I use javascript to solve the problem, using Audio objects and a setInterval. Below an example:

```
  var sndLetItSnow = new Audio("audio/letItSnow.m4a");
  var sndSanta = new Audio("audio/snow.m4a");

  var playlist = [sndLetItSnow, sndSanta];

  var current = null;
  var idx = 0;

  function playSound() {
      if (current === null || current.ended) {
          // go to next
          current = playlist[idx++];

          // check if is the last of playlist and return to first
          if (idx >= playlist.length)
              idx = 0;

           // return to begin
           current.currentTime=0;

           // play
           current.play();
      }

  }

  setInterval(playSound, 1000);
```

For more documentation on Audio object you can visit this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

I hope this help!