# call function (audio playing) in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hava a function that playing audios in order. But there may be a case where the function is called almost at the same time, and all audios playing is mixed. How can I call the same function where audios order of the second call is played after the audios order of the first call.

```
function playSound() {
  $('#content').append('<audio id="ding" src="ding.wav" preload="auto"></audio>');
  $('#ding')[0].play();
  $('#ding')[0].onended = function() {

    $('#content').append('<audio id="number" src="sound/voice/number.wav" preload="auto"></audio>');
    $('#number')[0].play();
    $('#number')[0].onended = function() {

      $('#content').append('<audio id="goToCounter" src="sound/voice/goToCounter.wav" preload="auto"></audio>');
      $('#goToCounter')[0].play();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try refering this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263816/17033432

Comment: Your audio should already start playing as the previous one ends. You can add a small delay using `setTimeout()` if needed. Also note that your code can be DRY'd up quite significantly using an array of file paths. That way you can use a single `audio` element and `ended` event handler.

Comment: Probably caused by the one sound file taking less time than the other. Either preload the sounds or build a queue type of system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to have a counter that counts the number of times the `playSound` function is called. If it is still in the middle of playing sounds, increase the counter, but `return` from the function. Only after the playing of the three sounds is finished, you call `playSound` again if there are still calls in the queue.

```js
    var numberOfTimesAudioHasStarted = 0;
    function playSound(buttonClicked) {
        if(buttonClicked === true){
            numberOfTimesAudioHasStarted++;
        }
        if(numberOfTimesAudioHasStarted > 1 && buttonClicked === true){
            return;
        }
        $('#content').append(
                '<audio id="ding" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/audiothumb_22779/227796222.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>');
        $('#ding')[0].play();
        $('#ding')[0].onended = function() {
            $('#content')
                    .append(
                            '<audio id="number" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/audiothumb_22779/227796222.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>');
            $('#number')[0].play();
            $('#number')[0].onended = function() {
                $('#content')
                        .append(
                                '<audio id="goToCounter" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/audiothumb_11413/114136296.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>');
                $('#goToCounter')[0].play();
                $('#goToCounter')[0].onended = function() {
                    numberOfTimesAudioHasStarted--;
                    if(numberOfTimesAudioHasStarted > 0){
                        playSound(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $('button').click(function() {
        playSound(true);
    });
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button>play</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this function keeps adding `audio` elements to the page every time the function runs. This is bad practice, since no two elements with the same `id` should be present on a page.

Comment: Great Klassiek! Thank you! but now there is another problem. What if I pass different params in function, and use this param as a src of audio?

Comment: That's a different story. Not really part of your original question. But anyway, you could declare a global array, then every time the function is called, save the sources of the audio in this array. Use the first of this array every time your function is called. If you can't figure this out yourself you can create a new question.